# Error attempting to generate apk - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, compiler-errors

I'm trying to generate the apk, but always the error! I can not find this duplicate class, how can I debug this?

When compiling directly on the cell phone, this does not happen.

> Duplicate zip entry
>   [classes.jar:com/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzabn.class]

ERROR

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Job failed, see logs for details
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.transform(ProGuardTransform.java:196)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:185)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:181)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't write [/home/hugorafaell/AndroidStudioProjects/android/community/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/release/jars/3/1f/main.jar] (Can't read [/home/hugorafaell/.android/build-cache/23c877abe604950e2d019157800b50fe5390c53a/output/jars/classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:com/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzabn.class]))
    at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:187)
    at proguard.OutputWriter.execute(OutputWriter.java:79)
    at proguard.ProGuard.writeOutput(ProGuard.java:427)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:175)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BaseProguardAction.runProguard(BaseProguardAction.java:54)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:254)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.access$000(ProGuardTransform.java:63)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform$1.run(ProGuardTransform.java:173)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:48)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:225)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't read [/home/hugorafaell/.android/build-cache/23c877abe604950e2d019157800b50fe5390c53a/output/jars/classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:com/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzabn.class])
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:188)
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:158)
    at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:176)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:com/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzabn.class]
    at proguard.io.JarWriter.getOutputStream(JarWriter.java:138)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:106)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:106)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:92)
    at proguard.io.ClassRewriter.read(ClassRewriter.java:68)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
    at 

proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
        at proguard.io.JarReader.read(JarReader.java:65)
        at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:65)
        at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:53)
        at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:184)
        ... 13 more
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Which gradle task are you trying to run? Usually, when you want to create an APK you run gradlew assembleRelease. When you do so, at which subtask does the build crash? The log tell you, that the issue might happen when proguard is running. Have you tried to disable proguard for the moment?